# Loop through records and update database on conditions

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table `Person`:

[image]

Where `ID` is the primary key, `Male` is the total number of males, `Female` is the total number of females, `Person_ID` column is fixed to 4, so maximum number of males + females is 4 (we don't have to validate this).

I need to insert/update into the last column `Is_Valid` values of `Yes` or `No`, to determine whether the record is valid.

Here is the logic: for example total number of males and females is 3, then there have to be 3 person IDs, or if total males and females is 2 then must have 2 person ID data.

So the record ID 3 and 4 is invalid, because record 3 - there are 2 people (1 male 1 female) but there is only 1 person ID, record 4 there is 1 person (1 female) but there is no person ID data at all.

I need to do this programmatically in the c# code, but first I want to know the queries that can solve this problem?

The logic I've been thinking is that:

- Loop through each row
- Get sum of Males + Females = a
- Somehow count the none-null Person ID cells = b
- if a == b then insert YES else insert NO

I don't know how to write the query (or stored procedure), I guess it would be a little bit complicated. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are personid columns fixed 4 columns?

Comment: @ShakeerMirza Yes

Comment: I think it would be better if you normalized your data, so that instead of having four Person_Id columns, you would have a primary table and a secondary table that would have columns for: Id, fkey to primary table, Male (bit), Female (bit), Person_Id. Then all four (or however many) records would point back to the same record in the primary table. With all your values fixed like this, when you decide you need five Person_Ids, you have to modify both your schema and your query. Otherwise, Long's answer should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET Is_Valid = CASE WHEN (
               Case when Person1_ID != '' or Person1_ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 else 0 end +
               Case when Person2_ID != '' or Person2_ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 else 0 end +
               Case when Person3_ID != '' or Person3_ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 else 0 end +
               Case when Person4_ID != '' or Person4_ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 else 0 end ) != Male + Female THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
```

Comment: Try this query, not sure whether it works fine since I do not have your table, update me if any run time issue –

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Demo   
(   
id integer not null primary key,
male integer NULL,   
female integer NULL,   
PersonId_1 integer null,
PersonId_2 integer null,   
PersonId_3 integer null,
PersonId_4 integer null,
IsValid bit not null
);  

insert into #Demo
(id, male, female, PersonId_1,PersonId_2,PersonId_3,PersonId_4,IsValid)
values
(1,1,1,2,2,null,null,0)

update #Demo
set IsValid = 1
where (#Demo.male + #Demo.female) = 
(case when #Demo.PersonId_1 IS NOT NULL Then 1 Else 0 end)+
(case when #Demo.PersonId_2 IS NOT NULL Then 1 Else 0 end)+
(case when #Demo.PersonId_3 IS NOT NULL Then 1 Else 0 end)+
(case when #Demo.PersonId_4 IS NOT NULL Then 1 Else 0 end)

select * from #Demo
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of looping

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (male + female) = isnull(personid_1 / personid_1, 0) 
                                  + isnull(personid_2 / personid_2, 0)
                                  + isnull(personid_3 / personid_3, 0)
                                  + isnull(personid_4 / personid_4, 0)
                THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
            END AS valid
    FROM PERSON
    )
UPDATE PERSON
SET IS_VALID = CTE.VALID
FROM CTE
WHERE PERSON.ID = CTE.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run an update statement for this, and don't have to loop through it. Or you can make the is_valid a computed column.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,male INT
,female INT
,person1_id INT
,person2_id INT
,person3_id INT
,person4_id INT
,is_valid AS CASE
    WHEN  (male + female = 1 AND person1_id IS NOT NULL AND person2_id IS NULL AND person3_id IS NULL AND person4_id IS NULL)
        OR (male + female = 2 AND person1_id IS NOT NULL AND person2_id IS NOT NULL AND person3_id IS NULL AND person4_id IS NULL)
        OR (male + female = 3 AND person1_id IS NOT NULL AND person2_id IS NOT NULL AND person3_id IS NULL AND person4_id IS NULL)
        OR (male + female = 4 AND person1_id IS NOT NULL AND person2_id IS NOT NULL AND person3_id IS NOT NULL AND person4_id IS NULL)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
)

INSERT @test (male,female,person1_id,person2_id,person3_id,person4_id)
VALUES
(1,1,200,700,NULL,NULL)
,(2,0,205,210,NULL,NULL)
,(1,1,240,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(0,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)

SELECT * FROM @test
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Male + Female` column values and compare them with number of columns that have non-null or empty values. If they are equal, set `Is_Valid` to 1 otherwise set it to 0.

```
update p
set Is_Valid =
                case
                    when Male + Female = (iif(Isnull(Person1_ID, '') = '', 0, 1) + iif(Isnull(Person2_ID, '') = '', 0, 1) +
                        iif(Isnull(Person3_ID, '') = '', 0, 1) + iif(Isnull(Person4_ID, '') = '', 0, 1)) then 'YES'
                    else 'NO'
                end

from Person p
```

Just to clarify the code below checks to see if the column has null value and makes it empty and then checks if it is empty, if yes makes it 0 otherwise makes it 1. This is done for each column:

```
iif(Isnull(Person1_ID, '') = '', 0, 1)
```

You can do this too to be more careful and check for whitespaces:

```
iif(Isnull(rtrim(ltrim(Person1_ID))), '') = '', 0, 1)
```